# Creating a shared mailbox for multiple users to send out and an auto responder with "Do not reply" message in Exchange 2007

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2007, auto-reply

I want to create a Do Not Reply shared mailbox. Multiple users need to be able to send out messages from this mailbox notify@contoso.com, but when anyone replies or sends to this mailbox, they get an automated message saying this is an unmonitored mailbox and your message will not be replied.

I'm using Exchange 2007 and have limited experience with mail servers in general, so the more detailed the response the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You just create an exchange-enabled "notify" user and enable all your users for [full mailbox access](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996343%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) to notify's mailbox.
2. You log on with the "notify" account and start Outlook (or use Outlook Web Access if it is enabled) and set up either an [Out-of-office reply](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290846) (there is Wizard functionality for this in Outlook) or a [message rule](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2008/04/14/3405360.aspx). In either case you will need to enable automatic reply messages to external recipients.

Another option would be using [transport rules](http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/transport-rules-exchange-server-2007.html).

The technical stuff put aside, it is a rather bad style from the workflow perspective to have a "do not reply" mailbox - the mail's recipients will have to care about finding the contact information to reply if they ever need to. If you want to do this for sending newsletters and simply do not want to receive all the "out of office" replies or message bounces, setting up an autoreply is the exact opposite of the "right thing (tm)" as it will create mail loops in some constellations.

Comment: +22 for the bad practice argument. I can't stress that enough!

Comment: @mailq you really have the right nick for answering this kind of question :)

Comment: As far as I know the command `mailq` is not available for Exchange ;-) But probably someone would do a PowerShell equivalent...